# foldLeft method in scala

Tags: scala

I am using the following code to get a count of words in a text

```
.foldLeft(Map.empty[String, Float]){
   (countsSource, wordSource) => countsSource + (wordSource -> (countsSource.getOrElse(wordSource, 0) + 1))}
```

I am getting an error that 1 should be a string. If i put it in quotes, it says that it should be a float.

What am I doing wrong?? Thanks for your help in advance

Comment: I am a novice at scala. I have been trying to change 1 to 1.0 with no effect!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getOrElse`'s signature is as follows:

```
def getOrElse[B1 >: B](key: A, default: => B1): B1
```

Which means it doesn't necessarily return the type of the Map's value (`B`), but potentially a superclass `B1`. In your case, using the literal `0` doesn't inform the compiler that you're interested in a `Float`.

Using `0f` instead would fix it:

```
l.foldLeft(Map.empty[String, Float]){
  (countsSource, wordSource) => countsSource + (wordSource -> (countsSource.getOrElse(wordSource, 0f) + 1))}
```